# Responsive design will not respond below 480

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

This is a site that I am coming into after the developer quit.  I have got everthing done but I noticed that it no responding below 480.

[Here is the site](http://www.explorescottcountyva.org/)

Here what I have in the head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Here the css for that part:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) { There some css in here  }
```

This is a custom template for wordpress that someone created.  So I am at alost I have worked many hours trying to figure out what is wrong with it.   I hope someone can help PLEASE!

Comment: remove @viewport {
width: 320px;
 max-zoom: 3;
 min-zoom: 0.50;
}

Comment: unfortunately, responsiveness is a bit more complicated than that. This needs a deeper look at how the css is set up to display within those parameters. And what css framework was it used as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should answer your question:

```
#footer .partners {
    float: none;
    width: 494px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This div is never going to get any smaller than 494px. It also will not let it's parent(s) get below the width of it's widest element, which is this one, which is why the entire site will not go below this width.

Comment: Thank you I must have missed that.  After look at it for so long I just looked over it.

Comment: We all have this problem. What I generally do when I see horizontal scrollbars is open up my inspector and set `display:none` to the immediate children of my body (usually just a few (header, footer, #body, and #hero) and see which one causes the horizontal scrollbar to go away - this would allow me to know roughly where the problem is occurring. Once I know it's in the, for example, footer - then I turn off the immediate elements of the footer one by one, and so on and so on.

Answer (score 0):

What this CSS is saying is that the rules said in your media query will be applied when the width of the screen is between 480px and 321px. If that is what you are trying to do, it seems to work fine. Here is some test CSS and the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8e36/) result (resize the JSFiddle window)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) { 
    body {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Can you be more specific in what your trying to achieve, it seems to work fine for me.